# Azure AD Multi-tenant App - Find what tenant provided admin consent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been looking all around for documentation and information regarding Azure AD multi-tenant applications in regards to who is using my application.

In Azure AD, I created an app registration and chose 'Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)'. I do not see any way to specify which tenants I do want to allow.

[image]

I am using Application Permissions which requires Admin Consent to use the app so a Global Administrator from each tenant would have to grant consent. However, I do not see any way to look into my app and see which tenant granted consent.

Background: I have built an application that does a user directory search across two tenants. Regardless who which user logins in from either tenant, they can search for users across both. I have App Registrations set up in both tenants with client secrets to get access tokens to search each directory.

Since my directory is hosting the app to log in, each tenant needs to grant admin consent to use the app. I am trying to make sure any other tenant outside of our two tenants cannot grant consent and use our app too.

1. Is there a way to restrict which tenant are allowed to use my app?
2. Is there a way to look into which tenant did allow my app?
3. If another org were to get ahold of my client id and grant consent, am I able to do anything to prevent them from using it?
4. Can I set up notifications if another org grants consent to my app?

Comment: I would say the answer is "out of the box, no" to all the questions, but I am not 100% certain. We are using our own backend database for all of those (to track the users and to grant the access). The browser or the app passes the token, the token contains tenant id (even the built-in), so the backend can check in (our) database if it's allowed tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to restrict which tenant are allowed to use my app?

You can restrict which tenant is allowed to use your app by specifying the list of tenants in the **Restrict-Access-To-Tenants** header

> Is there a way to look into which tenant did allow my app?

If you want to know the list of tenants/users who have access to your app, you should be user of that particular tenant.

> If another org were to get ahold of my client id and grant consent, am
> I able to do anything to prevent them from using it?

You can restrict which tenant can have to access to your application by using **Restrict-Access-To-Tenants** header in your application

> Can I set up notifications if another org grants consent to my app?

We cannot receive the notification if any other organization grants consent to your application

Comment: Note that using the Restrict-Access-To-Tenants header is not a supported or encouraged way for an app to restrict access to only certain tenants. (That is part of a paid feature used to restrict access from managed devices/networks to certain tenants.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to restrict which tenant are allowed to use my app?

The only safe way to do this currently is in your app's code. If users are signing in to your app, you do this by verifying that the ID token's issuer corresponds to one of the tenants you do allow. If your app accepts access tokens (i.e. it's an API), you do the same with the access token.

> Is there a way to look into which tenant did allow my app?

After the fact, no. If your app was the one that sent the user off to sign-in/consent, then after consent the browser will be sent back to the redirect URL, but there are several situations where consent/access is granted which would not result in that redirect. (Also, you don't want to rely on unprotected query parameters for something approaching access control, as a user count trivially intercept the redirect and change the parameter value.)

> If another org were to get ahold of my client id and grant consent, am I able to do anything to prevent them from using it?

Generally speaking, no. In certain situations it's possible to reduce the likelihood of this happening, but if your app is configured as a multi-tenant app, you must assume users from any organization are be able to sign in to it. If you need to restrict which organizations actually so use the app, you need to enforce this in your app's code.

> Can I set up notifications if another org grants consent to my app?

No, this isn't possible.